# Gatsby - EACCESS : permission denied for ".config/gatsby"

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

i try to install Gatsby on a VPS server where the ".config" folder at the ROOT User is not writable and unfornately like it's a managed VPS server, i don't have access to `SUDO`.

Installing Gatsby globally work (`npm i -g install gatsby-cli@4.1.25`) but then when i try to execute gatsby (`npx gatsby --version`) i have this error :

`
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.config/gatsby'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1386:3)
at AsyncFunction.pd.sync (/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:148531)
at Id.xd.globalConfigPath.set all [as all] (/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:156122)
at new Id.xd.globalConfigPath (/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:155852)
at Id (/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:155662)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:486943)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
```

`

My question is, do you know how to change the config path for the gatsby config folder for example
`/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.npm_config/.config/gatsby` instead of `/home/clients/3592698af9bb61958cc5c43ea0d81272/.config/gatsby`?

I guess that maybe Gatsby take a config variable from NPM but i don't know which one.

Thanks in advance =)

** What i already tried : **

In the Gatsby configuration, there is some link to troubleshoot if you have permissions problems :
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally
https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/main/npm-global-without-sudo.md

I tried it but it's for fixing npm -g install problem and it doesn't change the Gatsby config path.

Comment: The `i` and `install` options in your `npm` command are redundant: `i` is just an alias for `install`. So rather use either `npm install -g gatsby-cli@4.1.25` or `npm i -g gatsby-cli@4.1.25`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 4.1.25 version of the `gatsby-cli` package, which is probably part of the problem. If you run the following then you should see an error message:

```bash
npm install gatsby-cli@4.1.25
```

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for gatsby-cli@4.1.25.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Try without specifying a version.

```bash
npm install gatsby-cli
```

That will install the latest version of `gatsby-cli` under `node_modules` in the current working directory.

You should then be able to run it with `npx gatsby`.

Take a look at [this post](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2023/04/installing-gatsby/) for various approaches to installing Gatsby.